# CoreData doesn't upload data to iCloud immediately after store seeding

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I've noticed that after seeding my store CoreData doesn't send these data to iCloud immediately. In most cases, to force data upload I have to close the app, delete it from the background and launch again. After this procedure the app begins to upload its data. Is there any reason of such behavior? Is there any way to force app to upload its data to iCloud? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you save the context that should force transaction logs to be written immediately and the iCloud sync should commence.  If you are using the simulator you may have to use the Debug->iCloud Sync menu to trigger iCloud sync

Comment: I've just verified: saving context (after initial seeding/migration) doesn't help to propel iCloud sync. Still have to close app and start again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no API to force data sync. You have no control when device will replicate its data.

Comment: You save changes, which creates a transaction log, but it only uploads when the iCloud system decides to upload it. Usually it's soon but it's not guaranteed to be immediate.